# Spatial Data from Postgis to Java/REST with RestEasy + Jackson

Tags: postgis, geojson, rest, json

I'm developing an application where I take a route from google maps, save it in postgresql/postgis. I'd like to take this route (LineString geometry) and send it back to Google Maps.

I already can save the map in the database, now I want to show the routes on a map.

On the client side I'm using JQuery (AJAX) + Google Maps Api.
On the server side I'm using REST services with RestEasy.

I tried to work with Jackson to transform the Entity to JSON, but, the Jackson fails to transform geometric data in json. Does anyone know how to transform this spatial data into JSON?

**My Entity:**

```
public class Rota {
...
private LineString caminho;
public Rota() {
}
public Rota(Integer id, Usuario usuario, String descricao, LineString     lineString) {
    this.id = id;
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.caminho = lineString;
}
// getters and setters
@Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
public LineString getCaminho() {
    return caminho;
}
public void setCaminho(LineString caminho) {
    this.caminho = caminho;
}
// hashcode and equals method
}
```

**My REST service:**

```
@Inject
private RotaBC rotaBC;

@GET
@Path("/rotas/{idrota}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Rota show(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    return rotaBC.show(Integer.parseInt(id));
}
```

**The error:**

> 15:05:16,447 ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sharecar].[default]]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet default threw
>   exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException$Reference from [Module
>   "org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl:main" from local module
>   loader @1d332b (roots: /opt/demoiselle/server/jboss-7.1/modules)] ...
>   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:166)
>   ... at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:446)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:150)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:112)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you saving the route from google as a spatial object?

Comment: GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();

  Coordinate c[] = new Coordinate[pontos.length];
  String ap[];
  for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
   ap = pontos[i].split(",");
   c[i] = new Coordinate(Double.parseDouble(ap[0]), Double.parseDouble(ap[1]));
  }

  Rota r = new Rota(id, usuario, descricao, gf.createLineString(c));
  
  rotaBC.create(r);

Comment: By JavaScript I take the geometry add do this:
var a = aPontos.toString().substring(1, aPontos.toString().length - 1).split('),('); 
after I send the var **a** by ajax/post.

Comment: https://github.com/lusabo/sharecar

Comment: What are you saving in your database?

Comment: I'm saving a LineString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get json (or geojson) from PostGIS there is the function [ST_geojson()](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html) which will return a geometric object in `geojson` form.

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4

Comment: `ST_GeoJson` is a PostGIS function, not PostGreSQL

Comment: I know, but, the PostGIS that PostgreSQL 8.4 uses does not have this function.

Comment: Are you sure? According to the docs it was introduced in Postgis 1.3.4 http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html